# Kendo-popup anchor to conditional element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I had the following in my template which worked as expected and displayed the popup next to the anchor element:

```
<a title="Search" #searchAnchor (click)="toggleSearchPopup()">
  <icon [iconId]="'search'"></icon>
</a>

<kendo-popup #searchPopup
             [anchor]="searchAnchor"
             [anchorAlign]="anchorAlign"
             [popupAlign]="popupAlign"
             *ngIf="show">
  <!-- popup content... --> 
</kendo-popup>
```

I have now made the anchor element conditional with `ngIf` but the popup no longer shows next to the anchor, it shows at position `0, 0`:

```
<a *ngIf="loggedIn" title="Search" #searchAnchor (click)="toggleSearchPopup()">
  <icon [iconId]="'search'"></icon>
</a>
```

The IDE also warns me on the line `[anchor]="searchAnchor"` that `Unresolved variable or type searchAnchor`, presumably because the element with that id may not be present (although it always will be when the popup is shown).

The [kendo-popup docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/popup/aligning-positioning/#aligning-to-components) state that:

> If an anchor is not provided, the Popup will use the offset property
> value.

Which seems to be what is happening.

The only way I can think to get round this is to add a `<div>` or similar around the `<a>` and anchor to that instead:

```
<div #searchAnchor>
  <a *ngIf="loggedIn" title="Search" (click)="toggleSearchPopup()">
    <icon [iconId]="'search'"></icon>
  </a>
</div>
```

This anchors the popup next to the correct element again but is there a better way of doing this so that I can still anchor to the `<a>` but somehow tell it that it will be there when the popup opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by moving **both** the popup and anchor element inside an `<ng-container` element which has the `*ng-if`, as explained here in the docs:
https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue

The docs specifically discuss using HTML container element such as a `<div>` *(as I had tried)* stating that although this works it could have unintended consequences that break the appearance.

My working code is now:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="loggedIn">
  <a title="Search" #searchAnchor (click)="toggleSearchPopup()">
    <icon [iconId]="'search'"></icon>
  </a>

  <kendo-popup #searchPopup
             [anchor]="searchAnchor"
             [anchorAlign]="anchorAlign"
             [popupAlign]="popupAlign"
             *ngIf="show">
    <!-- popup content... --> 
  </kendo-popup>
</ng-container>
```

A simplified working example is shown here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ypkajr